# Unmask a PasswordTextBox?

Tags: gwt

Is it somehow possible to unmask a [PasswordTextBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PasswordTextBox.html)? I would like to have a textbox to enter a password and a checkbox, which says `Show Password`. If the user clicks the checkbox, the content of the Passwordcheckbox becomes unmasked. I could build a custom component using TextBox but it somehow seems the wrong path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you can do it, on selecting the checkbox do -

`passwordBox.getElement().setAttribute("type", "text");`

Set it back to password when u want to undo it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
passwdTextBox.getElement().setAttribute("type", "text");
```

This changes the type of input element from "password" to "text".